# Sharepoint solution not showing up in Site > Features

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I do not know alot about sharepoint and I am having trouble installing a sharepoint solution.

I am trying to install this package called "Workflow Actions for SharePoint Designer 2010" - It installs fine and I can see it inside "Central Administration -> Web applications -> Manage Features" and it is "ACTIVATED", But when I go to "Manage Features" of my site, I cannot see it there.

What Am I doing wrong here? If i go and select the "Feature.xml" file it says

Scope="WebApplication"

How do I fix this problem?

**EDIT:** I actually need to make a call to a webservice when a workflow starts, and this package seems to offer that. If there is any other package that I can use to call webservice that will also solve my problem. Thanks!

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Install%20Workflow%20Actions%20for%20SharePoint%20Designer%202010&referringTitle=Workflow%20Actions%20for%20SharePoint%20Designer%202010

Answer (score 0):

If you want a feature to be installed at your Site Scope then you can change the scope to Site from the feature properties in the feature you have created.

Answer (score 0):

Well after going through a dozen different things I was able to install it myself. Looks like the documentation on the link i gave out above does not work, or atleast it didnt work for me.

I had to force enable it by running powershell and running the command.

enable-spfeature -Identity {GUID} -url {URL}

To find the GUID -  goto 14/Templates/ILSPSPDActions and edit the Feature.XML file. It has a GUID in it.

Although after running the above command, the option still didn't appear inside Site Collections -> Site Features -- But it did the trick. Once executed successfully, restart the Sharepoint Designer 2010 and its workflow actions menu will have additional actions in it.

Hope this helps someone.